# start something after PFQuery is finished

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfquery

Is there a possibility to do something AFTER a query is done? I have a PFQuery that queries objects, the objectIds of these objects will be apendet to an Array. materUserObjects is an PFUser, MatesIdsAndNames is a dictionary, the rest are String  `func queryNow(){

```
    if mateUserObject.isEmpty == false{

        for mateId in mateUserObject{



            let date = NSDate()
            let dateInt = date.timeIntervalSince1970

            let query = PFQuery(className: "calendarEvents")
            query.whereKey("createdBy", equalTo: mateId)
            query.whereKey("StartDate", lessThan: dateInt)
            query.whereKey("EndDate", greaterThan: dateInt)
            query.cachePolicy = .NetworkOnly
            query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

                if error != nil{
                    print(error)
                }else{

                    if objects?.isEmpty == true{
                        self.freeMateIds.append(mateId.objectId!)
                        print(self.freeMateIds)
                        if self.mateUserObject.last == mateId{


                            if self.freeMateIds.isEmpty == false{


                                for freeMate in self.freeMateIds{

                                    let oneFreeMate = self.matesIdsAndNames[freeMate]
                                    self.freeMateNames.append(oneFreeMate!)
                                    print(self.freeMateNames)
                                }

                            }
                            self.MatesTableView.reloadData()

                        }

                    }

                }


            })



        }


    }


}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you use query.findObjectInBackgroundWithBlock? If yes I would suggest you to use a competition handler:

```
typealias CompletionHandler = (success: Bool) -> Void

//  Ajoute dans le tableau _applications les applications stockées sur Parse
func fetchData(completionHandler: CompletionHandler) {
    let query = PFQuery(className: "Test")
    var supposeObjectCount: Int = 0
    var objectCount: Int  = 0

    //  Ajoute un filtre pour la requete
    query.orderByAscending("Id")

    //  Trouve les objets sur Parse
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        //  S'il n'y a pas d'erreur
        if error == nil {

            supposeObjectCount = objects!.count


            if let objects = objects {


                for object in objects {

                    // ..

                    if(supposeObjectCount == ++objectCount) {
                        completionHandler(success: true)
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        else {
            print("Error")
        }
    }
}



//  Call the function

func test() {
    fetchData({ (success) -> Void in


        if success {
            //  Executed when query is completed
        }
    })
}
```

Hope this help!

Comment: It's a bit more complex I guess, the problem is that I have an Array of PFUser ( mateUserObject), I go through that Array by: for mate in mateUserObject... within this for loop I query events that were created by this user.. so maybe it's the for loop that is not done yet? I try to upload my code soon, I'm on my iPad at the moment.. so as a short description: a for loop goes through an array, every time it picks an object there is a query based on the object. I tried catching the last time the loop is executed by using: if mateUserObject.last == mate { print(mateUserObject)

Comment: Otherwise if you don't matter about a delay when you use a PFQuery instead of using query.findObjectInBackgroundWithBlock(), you could use let objects = query.findObjects() and after that you do a for object in objects and in this for loop you do another query let objectsV2 = query.findObjects() and after that you do another for loop... It's not the best way to use the findObjects() because it freeze the main thread but it could be a solution. I hope you understand what I mean :) You could most likely do this using findObjectInBackground instead of the findObjects() that freeze the main thread

Comment: To be honest I don't really get what you mean :D But thanks a lot for trying to help me, I really appreciate that!!! Let's try it the other way around, is there a possibility to start a function after the for loop? For example, the array has 20 objects, I want to do something after the loop went through all these 20? Cause if I just type it beneath the for loop, it may be executed while the loop is still running right?

Comment: There's two type of query.findObject with parse. The first one: query.findObjects() will freeze the main thread so when the query would be executed all your program will freeze. While the query is executed, you would not be able to do anything except the home button of the device. The second type of query is: query.findObjectInBackgroundWithBlock... This will query the data in the background of your application so you would be able to navigate though the app. So do you care if your app freeze the time of your query or you prefer to do all this in the background?

Comment: I know get what you mean, but unfortunately I don't think that helps.. I really think it's the for loop... does the for loop always go through an array in the same direction? I mean if I have an Array,[1,2,3,4,5,6], will: for numbers in Array {...} always start with 1 and end with 6? If you don't know that, it's no problem, I'm really thankful for what you already did for me :)

Comment: If when you loop in the array you don't add data, the loop should read 1,2,3,4,5,6 but if you add data during the process i think she might give result in a different order :)

Comment: I got to edit my question and enter the code, print(self.freeMateNames) sometimes shows all the names ( I know which names should be there :D ) , and sometimes only shows a few of them...